# Update many flag columns given the value of other columns (NULL values) in the same record

Tags: sql-server-2005, flags, dbnull, data-integration

Given a table of input data I would like to have a set o **"flag columns" that describe sibling columns of the same record**.

- I am using Microsoft **SQL Server 2005**.
- First of all I need to load data in the target table, then I need to perform checks to put values in those flag columns.

Say for example I have a toy table like the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE zzz_test
             (
                          color        VARCHAR(10),
                          value_x      INTEGER    ,
                          value_y      INTEGER    ,
                          value_x_FLAG bit        ,
                          value_y_FLAG bit
             )
```

Then I have the following toy data (I need to repeat the INSERT/VALUES statements for every record because of the "old" 2005 SQL version):

```
INSERT zzz_test(color,value_x,value_y)
VALUES('red',1,NULL)
INSERT zzz_test(color,value_x,value_y)
VALUES('green',NULL,NULL)
INSERT zzz_test(color,value_x,value_y)
VALUES('red',NULL,2)
INSERT zzz_test(color,value_x,value_y)
VALUES('red',1,3)
INSERT zzz_test(color,value_x,value_y)
VALUES('black',NULL,1)
INSERT zzz_test(color,value_x,value_y)
VALUES(NULL,3,2)
INSERT zzz_test(color,value_x,value_y)
VALUES('black',1,2)
INSERT zzz_test(color,value_x,value_y)
VALUES('red',3,4)
INSERT zzz_test(color,value_x,value_y)
VALUES('green',1,1)
INSERT zzz_test(color,value_x,value_y)
VALUES('blue',5,NULL)
```

Now I would like to have a quick way to put values inside `value_x_FLAG` and `value_y_FLAG` evaluating if sibling columns `value_x` and `value_y` are **`NULL`**.

I know that there are functions like `ISNULL()`, or `COALESCE()`, but I do not think this is the case because **I am trying to update a column given the value of another column**.

I know I can use `IF / ELSE` statements but it's quite complicate to set all the cases of many boolean flags (2^n) to work all together in the same "update" statement of the flag variables.

How to deal with it?

After setting all the flags I would like to summarize in some way my table. For example I would like to have a `COUNT` on all the flag variables, then I would like to have a `COUNT` given the "*color category*".

Probably I do not need a set of support flag variables, but I would like to have them to make the table much more readable, and also the SQL code much more readable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, after all inserts, do

```
update zzz_test set value_x_FLAG = CASE value_x when null then 1 else 0 END, value_y_FLAG = CASE value_y when null then 1 else 0 END
```

hope it works!

edit: about the count, you can use group by clause everytime you need it, instead of have a flag saved in somewhere

```
select Color, Count(value_x_FLAG) from zzz_test  group by Color having value_x_FLAG != 0
```

this will return a 2 column table, with the color and int the other column the number of rows that have the flag = 1

Comment: I just tryied it, but it sets all the flags to 0. I think there should be some trick to add to the `when null` to let the system fall into that case, any idea?

Comment: try `..CASE value_x when IS NULL..`

Comment: I also tried the `GROUP BY` statement, but it gives me errors saying that the column in the `HAVING` clause is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: The `IS NULL` attempt failed saying *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'*.

Comment: try this `select Color, Count(value_x_FLAG) from zzz_test  where value_x_FLAG != 0 group by Color ` Sorry for that, I'm recently wake up and working haha. (and sorry for the bad English)

Comment: there it is. Look here http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Select-Query/UseCASEintheUPDATEstatement.htm
it will be `update zzz_test set value_x_FLAG = CASE when value_x is null then 1 else 0 END, value_y_FLAG = CASE when value_y  is null then 1 else 0 END`. This should work, or definitely need a coffe